# How can i activate multiple views belonging to the same region?

Tags: silverlight, prism

I'm new to Silverlight and Prism. I'm developing a dashboard application.
Here's my question.
I've 2 regions: 1. Login 2. Maincontainer.

My Login region has one view and my maincontainer has 2 views.

After a successful login, i need to deactivate the Login region or view (whichever is simple) and then i need to activate the Maincontainer region and both the view within it.
Is there a way i can activate both the view of my "Maincontainer" region at the same time?
Any help would be useful.

Thanks in advance 
Samit

Answer (score 3):

To activate a view in a region means to display it. If you want a region which can display more than one view at the same time, you must use an AllActiveRegion. To use regions of this kind you must use as a region host an ItemsControl (or any other that inherits from it).

You can find some more info [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/matiasb/2009/07/02/how-to-hide-views-inside-composite-application-guidance-aka-prism-v2-regions/).

I hope this helps.